# How to launch a PopupWindow or Dialog from an input method service?

Tags: android, android-widget

I get the same exception when I try to pop a PopupWindow (or Dialog) from InputMethodService:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:505)
     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:828)
     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:688)
     at mypackage.MyInputMethodService.onClick(MyInputMethodService.java:123)
     ...
```

If I try to pop a Dialog instead, I get the exact same exception in the exact same line of ViewRoot.java. Here is my code (abridged):

```
public class MyInputMethodService
    extends InputMethodService 
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // This is the handler for View.OnClickListener
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example, null, false), 100, 100, true);
        pw.showAtLocation(mInputView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        // mInputView was previously created and returned by onCreateInputView()
    }
} // end of MyInputMethodService
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Test Pop-Up"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried many variations of the above code but always get the same exception for PopupWindows and Dialogs. For some reason Toast alerts work. Is there a special technique for launching a PopupWindow or Dialog from a **Service** (specifically an InputMethodService), as opposed to an Activity?

Thanks in advance,

Barry

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually i managed to do it try this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                 builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
                 builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                 {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
                    {
                       // Do something with the selection
                    }
                 });
                 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                 Window window = alert.getWindow();
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
                 lp.token = mInputView.getWindowToken();
                 lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG;
                 window.setAttributes(lp);
                 window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
                 alert.show();
```

Comment: What class did you call that from? InputMethodService or KeyboardView?

Comment: InputMethodService give it a try and let me know if this is an answer to you

Comment: Works as you said. Thank you!

Comment: What is `mInputView` in this context?

Comment: Getting error: `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: @Roymunson Can you please tell me if you found any solution?

Comment: @Starwave Can you please tell me too if you found any solution ?

Comment: @Chirag Prajapati In the end I believe it was simply not possible to launch alert window from input method service (maybe the only exception was when app had some very low level permissions, but those are not available for us normal app devs). In the end, I launched a separate activity and showed my info there.