# How open ProgressDialog from InputMethodService

Tags: java, android

Why i get error from Eclipse on below code?

**Code:**

```
public class ServiceKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener
 {
   public  static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

...
   @Override public void onStartInput( EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting)
    {
      super.onStartInput( attribute, restarting);
      progressDialog = new ProgressDialog( ServiceKeyboard.this);
      progressDialog.setMessage( getString( R.string.sSpinner));
// after this line crash
      progressDialog.show();
...
...
      if( progressDialog != null)  progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
```

**Error:**

```
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:589)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at com.avanpost.mobile.ServiceKeyboard.onStartInput(ServiceKeyboard.java:354)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.doStartInput(InputMethodService.java:1549)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.startInput(InputMethodService.java:388)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:158)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-23 12:53:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(23963):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is best solution to open window with progressDialog when softKeyboard (InputMethodService) start?

I try "new ProgressDialog( this);", "new ProgressDialog( getApplicationContext());" instead "new ProgressDialog( ServiceKeyboard.this);", but fail.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when creating an InputMethodService with no associated Activity.

This only works in API version 12 and greater, but I managed to get a ProgressDialog to display by passing in the window token used by the input view. As long as that happens, the ProgressDialog can be constructed with the application context.

The reason this requires API version 12 is that the InputMethodService must implement OnAttachStateChangeListener in order to be notified when the input view is attached to a window; trying to execute that code earlier results in a null token. It's likely there's another place later in the lifecycle to put the token request, but since my IME already had these API requirements, I didn't bother looking for one.

The code:

```
public class SampleKeyboardService extends InputMethodService
                                   implements OnAttachStateChangeListener {
  private View mInputView;
  private ProgressDialog mProgress;

  @Override
  public View onCreateInputView() {
      super.onCreateInputView();
      LayoutInflater inflater =
          (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      mInputView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input, null);
      mInputView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
      return mInputView;
  }

  /* ... */

  @Override
  public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
      Window progressWindow = mProgress.getWindow(); // mProgress created earlier
      WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = progressWindow.getAttributes();
      layoutParams.token = view.getWindowToken();
      layoutParams.type = 
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG;
      progressWindow.setAttributes(layoutParams);
  }
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13962770/793212

Answer (score 0):

Try to call ProgressDialog from the Activity. It will resolve your problem. Give me more explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Application not have activities. Application is SoftKeyboard on own InputMethodService. Can i generate ProgressDialog from InputMethodService without any activity?

Comment: You can't do it from Service... Instead you can call an activity.. this will resolve your issue...

Comment: It is any way to block user's inputs and block (freeze) user's inteface (activity of alient app) on my trigger in IME (softKeyboard), when open and work alient apllication? I need execute my long operation in my IME, and when it is continues execute i need block user manipulation to the end of my operation.

Comment: Guna, thanx fo your answer. But creating activity with ProgressDialog in not applicable for my case. I need access to editable views of activity's of alient app's from my IME, and if i create my activity i lose access to this views...